# How show hidden and system folder/files?

Tags: dired

Emacs 26.1. , **Dired+**

Here content folder `TraderMonitor` in Total Commander:

[image]

and here how look same folder (`TraderMonitor`) in Emacs, **dired** mode:

[image]

How show hidden/system folders:

```
.git
.idea
```

and file:

```
.gitignore
```

?

P.S.
If I start by `emacs -Q`  I see all this hidden files:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

What is the value of option `dired-listing-switches`? If you are telling `ls` not to list dot files ("hidden" files) then they will not be shown by Dired.

Do you have `dired-omit-mode` turned on? If so, what are the values of options `dired-omit-files` and `dired-omit-extensions`?

Even with vanilla Dired, file names with extensions such as `.git` are matched by the default value of `dired-omit-extensions`, so they will not show when `dired-omit-mode` is turned on.

Do you see the same behavior if you start Emacs without your init file: `emacs -Q` and you use only vanilla Dired? If you start Emacs without your init file and you use Dired+?

Dired is quite configurable, and Dired+ is even more so. Whether to show such files is up to you.

Comment: dired-listing-switches = -l, dired-omit-mode - Nothing to omit

Comment: `dired-listing-switches` should be set to `-la` in order to show "hidden" files.

Comment: I updated my post

Comment: @NickD where you find options "-la" ? In help has only this options:    "May contain all other options that don’t contradict ‘-l’;
   may contain even ‘F’, ‘b’, ‘i’ and ‘s’ "

Comment: `dired-listing-switches` is the list of switches that `dired` calls `ls` with. See the doc string for `dired-listing-switches` and the man page for `ls`.

Comment: This answer contains several useful comments.  Could it be rephrased as an answer, rather than a series of questions?

Comment: Strange... Even though my `dired-omit-extensions` does contain `.git` directory, when in the `dired-omit-mode` it still shows up.